# unable to apply default page Length for datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I don't found any issue in this code.
But unable to apply pageLength for table.
Please help

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#Campaign_Overview').DataTable({
    "pageLength": 5,
    "lengthMenu": [5, 10, 25, 50 ]
  });
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @Aaditi have you tried removing lengthMenu.  Not sure, but that seems redundant if specifying pageLength.

Comment: @Aaditi Here is an example. I am assuming you want 5 items per page, correct?  http://jsfiddle.net/9m5g420u/2/

Comment: Thank you. Issue solved.

I removed Colspan from table headers and added two more columns for percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved.

I removed ***Colspan***  from table headers and added two more columns for percentage.

```
<thead>
   <tr>
    <th >Month</th>
    <th >WK</th>
    <th>OLI</th>
    <th>Campaign</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Target</th>
    <th style="text-align:right" >Delivered</th>
    <th style="text-align:left" >%age</th>
    <th style="text-align:right" >Deficit</th>
    <th style="text-align:left" >%age</th>
    <th style="text-align:center">Delivery Date</th>
</tr>
```